# POWER BI: Creating a calculated field based on multiple filters

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I am fairly new to Power Bi and have searched in various online help forums but was unsuccessful in finding the one similar to mine. Hence posting this here. Not sure if this is a fairly straightforward one or complicated (as I think!)

I have 3 columns: 'Event', 'Screen' and 'Time' (Similar to below)

[image]

I want do a single calculation as below:

> (2*count of "NameSubmitted" occurrences in **Event**) - (AVG **Time** of corresponding "NameSubmitted" (from **Event**) * count of "NameSubmitted" occurrences in **Event**)
>
> +
>
> (2*count of "AddressAdded" occurrences in **Event**) - (AVG **Time** of corresponding "AddAddress" (from **screen**) * count of "AddressAdded" occurrences in **Event**)
>
> +
>
> (2*count of "OrderCreated" occurrences in **Event**) - (AVG **Time** of corresponding sum of "Orders"+"OrderDetail"+"OrderConfirmation" (from **screen**) * count of "OrderCreated" occurrences in **Event**)`

**My approach:**

I have tried to create a new column with the following `IF()` function calculation but in vain (Started like below) and been receiving the following error:

`Calc = 
CALCULATE(
    (2*SUM(IF(Table[Event] = "NameSubmitted",1,BLANK())))
        - AVERAGE(IF(Table[Event] = "NameSubmitted")
     ))  .....`

> Error: The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to give a complete answer, but the last piece should look something like this:

```
= 2 * COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1, Table1[Event] = "OrderCreated"))
    - CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[Time]),
          Table1[Screen] IN {"Orders", "OrderDetail", "OrderConfirmation"})
    * COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1, Table1[Event] = "OrderCreated"))
```

Note: It's more efficient if you factor out the `COUNTROWS()`:

```
= COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1, Table1[Event] = "OrderCreated")) *
  (2 - CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[Time]),
           Table1[Screen] IN {"Orders", "OrderDetail", "OrderConfirmation"}))
```

You should be able to get the rest from there.

---

There are a variety of ways to count occurrences instead of using `COUNTROWS()`. The closest to your attempt would probably be like this:

```
= SUMX(Table1, IF(Table1[Event]="NameSubmitted", 1, BLANK()))
```

Comment: `Countrows()` worked brilliantly! I didn't know there is one such function. Thanks for that.